# How to associate between 2 models which are not directly related in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have 5 tables/models. Here are the structures.

```
1. application
id
name

2. profiles
id
name
app_id (Foreign key application table: id)

3. app_profiles
id
profile_id (Foreign key profile table: id)
app_id (Foreign key application table: id)

4. segments
id
app_id (Foreign key application table: id)

5. profile_segments
id
app_profile_id (Foreign key app_profile table: id)
segment_id (Foreign key segment table: id)
```

Here are my associations:

**application.rb**

```
  has_many :profiles, through: :app_profiles
  has_many :segments
  has_many :app_profiles
```

**profile.rb**

```
  has_many :applications, through: :app_profiles
  has_many :app_profiles
```

**app_profile.rb**

```
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :application
  has_many :segments, through: :profile_segments
  has_many :profile_segments
```

**segment.rb**

```
  has_many :profiles, through: :app_profiles
  has_many :app_profiles, through: :profile_segments
  has_many :profile_segments
  belongs_to :application
```

**profile_segment.rb**

```
belongs_to :app_profile
belongs_to :segment
```

Now the problem is I need to make an association between profile and profile_segment. Can this be done? If so how?

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make an association," but don't you already have access between `profile` and `profile_segment` (albeit indirectly) via `app_profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **profile.rb** add:

```
has_many :profile_segments, through: :app_profiles
```

Rails supports chained `has_many through:` statements. Your `AppProfile` model already `has_many :profile_segments` and `Profile` `has_many :app_profiles`, so you can chain them.

Under the hood, `ActiveRecord` will perform 2 `INNER JOIN`s when you do stuff like `profile.profile_segments`. You can see the full SQL statement in the debug output of your `rails server`. Even I am not sure how exactly rails does its magic :D

And may I say, I don't know what you are trying to achieve but your structure is very complex. Try to remove some models- probably add them as some columns in other models.

I had to make this to understand your structure:

[image: model dependency diagram]

`profile_segment` belongs to `application` via 2 paths. Definitely not a good thing. Maybe it should belong to `profile` rather than `app_profile`

Comment: Thanks, but changing the structure is not something I can do, a lot of other things depend on it. Now about this answer: has_many :profile_segments, through: :app_profiles, doesnt this mean, app_profiles will have the foreign keys of profile_segments? Its not the case. Profile_segments has a column with app_profile_id, not vice versa!

Comment: @defiant no, only `belongs_to` means that foreign key is present. Did you try my answer? It should just work with your current structure. `ActiveRecord` will make the necessary inner joins in SQL

Comment: it worked. I was doing the wrong select statement. Anyway can you please explain how did this has_many statement made the association? Thanks a lot.